# Segfault during static initialization when linking gcc-built Boost into an Intel C++-compiled program

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, icc

I have an Ubuntu 13.04 system with the latest SVN version of the Boost C++ libraries installed. The Boost installation was built using the system's native `gcc` version, v4.7.3. I use Boost pretty extensively, and it works very well when I compile using `gcc`; I have used many of them, including Boost.Thread (which I will talk about more below), without any issues.

My problem occurs if I try to build a program using the Intel C++ compiler (I've personally used a few different versions in the v13.x series) that link with the installed Boost libraries. When I do so, I get a segmentation fault immediately after program startup; it appears to occur during static initialization of the Boost.Thread library. Here's a simple example program:

```
#include <boost/version.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
}
```

I compile it using Intel C++:

```
icpc test.cc -lboost_thread -lboost_system -I/path/to/boost/inc/dir -L/path/to/boost/lib/dir
```

As I said, when I run the resulting program, I get a near-immediate segfault. Via `gdb`, the stack trace from the point of the segfault is as follows:

```
#0  0x00007ffff79b6351 in boost::exception_ptr boost::exception_detail::get_static_exception_object<boost::exception_detail::bad_exception_>() () from ./libboost_thread.so.1.55.0
#1  0x00007ffff79b02e1 in _GLOBAL__sub_I_thread.cpp () from ./libboost_thread.so.1.55.0
#2  0x00007ffff7de9876 in call_init (l=l@entry=0x7ffff7ff9a10, argc=argc@entry=1, 
    argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffe0b8, env=env@entry=0x7fffffffe0c8) at dl-init.c:84
#3  0x00007ffff7de9930 in call_init (env=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, 
    argc=<optimized out>, l=0x7ffff7ff9a10) at dl-init.c:55
#4  _dl_init (main_map=0x7ffff7ffe268, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe0b8, env=0x7fffffffe0c8)
    at dl-init.c:133
#5  0x00007ffff7ddb68a in _dl_start_user () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#6  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007fffffffe391 in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Not very enlightening, but it's clearly dying during the initialization of `libboost_thread.so`. If I rebuild Boost including debug symbols, then I get a slightly better picture:

```
#0  shared_count (r=..., this=0x7ffff7bbc5f8 <boost::exception_ptr boost::exception_detail::get_static_exception_object<boost::exception_detail::bad_exception_>()::ep+8>)
    at ./boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:328
#1  shared_ptr (this=0x7ffff7bbc5f0 <boost::exception_ptr boost::exception_detail::get_static_exception_object<boost::exception_detail::bad_exception_>()::ep>) at ./boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:328
#2  exception_ptr (ptr=..., this=0x7ffff7bbc5f0 <boost::exception_ptr boost::exception_detail::get_static_exception_object<boost::exception_detail::bad_exception_>()::ep>)
    at ./boost/exception/detail/exception_ptr.hpp:53
#3  boost::exception_detail::get_static_exception_object<boost::exception_detail::bad_exception_> () at ./boost/exception/detail/exception_ptr.hpp:130
#4  0x00007ffff79b02e1 in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (__initialize_p=<optimized out>, __priority=<optimized out>) at ./boost/exception/detail/exception_ptr.hpp:143
#5  _GLOBAL__sub_I_thread.cpp(void) () at libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp:767
#6  0x00007ffff7de9876 in call_init (l=l@entry=0x7ffff7ff9a10, argc=argc@entry=1, argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffe0b8, env=env@entry=0x7fffffffe0c8) at dl-init.c:84
#7  0x00007ffff7de9930 in call_init (env=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, argc=<optimized out>, l=0x7ffff7ff9a10) at dl-init.c:55
#8  _dl_init (main_map=0x7ffff7ffe268, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe0b8, env=0x7fffffffe0c8) at dl-init.c:133
#9  0x00007ffff7ddb68a in _dl_start_user () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#10 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007fffffffe391 in ?? ()
#12 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

It's unclear to me what static/global object is causing the problem to occur, so I'm not sure how to proceed. I have duplicated this behavior using a number of Boost versions and a few different versions of the Intel C++ compiler in the v13.x series, which is the only release that I have access to at the moment. I have tried every compiler permutation (i.e. I have built Boost with both `gcc` and `icpc` and I've built my test application with both also); the only permutation that fails is where Boost is built with `gcc` and my test application is built using `icpc`. In every other case, the test application runs successfully.

With that said, you might be led to the obvious answer:

- **Why not just rebuild Boost using `icpc` and call it a day?** That approach would seem to be effective, given my experimentation, but I have customers who like to use `icpc` to build my software. Those same customers are likely to have a Linux-distro-provided Boost package installed; they do not have any control over the build environment that was used to generate that package (and, in all likelihood, it was compiled using `gcc` anyway). Therefore, if it is possible to support such a mixed-compiler configuration, that would be optimal.

Does anyone have any recommendations as to how I might address this static initialization issue?

Comment: I don't really know icpc but have you tried to link with pthread? Just a wild guess.

Answer (score 4):

This is a long shot, but... If you have a different `g++` in your `PATH` than the one used to build the Boost libraries, get rid of it or pass `-gxx-name /usr/bin/g++` to `icpc`. (The Intel compiler adapts itself to the version of GCC it thinks you are using. `-gxx-name` lets you force the issue.)

OK that probably did not help.

Ubuntu 13.04 is not supported prior to Intel Composer XE 2013 SP1, aka. compiler version 14.0.0. See the ["System Requirements" section of the Release Notes](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/407601/release-notes-c-2013sp1-l-en.pdf#page=6) and compare it to the [same section for the last 13.x release](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/251095/release-notes-c-2013-l-en-update5.pdf#page=7).

Intel definitely aims for link compatibility with GCC. If you can reproduce this problem on a clean install of a supported version of Linux, you should be able to submit a support ticket and get it fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I only have access to v13.x at the moment, so I will try to duplicate it on a supported platform and see if that helps.

Comment: I was able to duplicate the problem on v13.0.1 using Ubuntu 12.04, which is a supported platform. I suppose I should try reporting it to Intel as a bug.

Comment: @JasonR: I would. Note that the first person who reads your report will be a "level 1" drone, so your objective is to convince them it is a real bug so they will bump you up the chain. Keep it short, provide a minimal test case, and give very literal "steps to reproduce". Ubuntu 12.04 is good since its an LTS release. Good luck :-).